# Asp.net Core 2.0 Issue storing custom objects in session

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core

I am creating a new website with **Asp.net Core 2.0 MVC**

In an webforms app I am used to doing something like this with my custom objects

```
Session["security"] = mySecurity;
mySecurity = Session["security"];
```

Now my issue is that the good old Asp.net session does not exist in Core. Following the example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x I have done:

- Added the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session (2.0.1) nuget packange
- Setup my Startup.cs to have the app.UseSession() and .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
- Added the extension methods listed to serialize and deserialize any object using Json

I have been able to successfully store and retrieve the Json string.

**The problem is that any of my private setters do not get restored.**

```
public class Security
{
    public userName { get; set;}
    public userLevel { get; private set;}
}
```

In this scenario the user name would be restored but the user level would not. I don't like it, but for the time being I have changed all of my members to just be public, but there has to be a better way. In this case it is my own object in which I can update, but if I wanted to store an object that is part of a library I can't just change the members to public.

This seems like a huge problem, but I have not been able to find an official solution. The only other thing I can think of is to try and convert my object to/from a byte array but I see articles stating not to do that.

I would love to know if anyone has found a good solution to this.

Comment: Well, an excellent approach is to forgo storing objects like this in the session. ASP.NET Core briefly flirted with removing `Session` altogether, but ultimately relented. In truth, there's good uses for the session, but 99.99% of the things people actually use sessions for are not those.

Comment: Have you tried serializing the object?

Comment: TheRuler Yes I have tried the Json serializer but it is not restoring private fields. @ChrisPratt I agree that often people overuse sessions but in this case I think I have an appropriate case. When the user logs in I create a security object that lets me access a few variables associated with their account. This is much more efficient than say only tracking their user ID and requerying their information on each page load. My temporary solution is just to make all my members public, but its an ugly solution.

Comment: You could use something like a JWT, which would be *much* more secure. Short of that, you can simply cache your query, so you get the best of both worlds: only storing an id in the session, but still having the user information without actually having to query for it. There's almost always alternatives to using sessions and they almost always better.